# Set default chip in Angular material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

I would select *web* a default chip when page loads.

```
     <mat-chip-list #chipsList >
        <mat-chip (click)="selectedChip(elm)" color="accent" selected="true" *ngFor="let elm of objectKeys" [value]="elm" color="accent">
          {{elm}}
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
```

Actually no chip is selected. What I would is select the first chip of the list.

When I `console.log(this.chipsList)` I see that all the items selected filed is set to true but no one is focused in UI.

How can I default select a chip?

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-default-select?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Have you got solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change selected="Web" to [selected]="this.selected === elm"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **index** inside ngFor:

```html
 <mat-chip (click)="selectedChip(elm)" color="accent" [selected]="index === 0" *ngFor="let elm of objectKeys; let index = index" [value]="elm" color="accent">
          {{elm}}</mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-default-select-vsexxr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Or even better, **first**:

```html
[selected]="first" *ngFor="let elm of objectKeys; let first = first"
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.  in your example, first chips list does not have the same color, and Web chip is not focused ( with shadow )

Answer (score 0):

First set default value in typescript:

```
tmpindex: number = 0;
```

Now in your html like this.

```
<mat-chip (click)="selectedChip(elm);tmpindex=i;" 
          color="accent" [selected]="i===tmpindex" 
          *ngFor="let elm of objectKeys; let i = index" 
          [value]="elm" color="accent">
     {{elm}}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Here is working example: [Set default chip list](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-default-select-uxrtwr)

Hope this helps!!!!